# How to create an R function that doesn’t need ‘$’ specified for columns

Tags: r

Somewhat new to programming and I want to try to make a custom function made in R easier to use, and less redundant.

How do I go from a custom function looking like this when in use:

`Function(data=df, x=df$x, y=df$y)`

Into:

`Function(data=df, x=x, y=y)`

As my function definition looks something like this now:

`Function <- function(data, x, y){ does whatever… }`

Specifically, I don’t want to have to use the $ operator for every variable input. I just want to use the df I have as an argument for ‘data’. How would I set it up differently?

Thanks!

Comment: If both `x` and `y` are derived from the same `df`, perhaps there is no need to supply all 3 arguments to the function? Just use `function(data = df)`, then use `df$x` and `df$y` inside the function?

Comment: @neilfws That’s a good idea, but I need to have x and y inputs flexible.

Comment: @DylanG But that is the way to make it flexible. If you pass a df to a function, you will always be able to access its columns. You can also pass the column names as strings and access `df[[x]]` and `df[[y]]`. Or pass the symbols and use non-standard evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Go with enqouting your arguments,
something like this

```r
sum2vars <- function(data, x, y) {
  x <- rlang::ensym(x)
  y <- rlang::ensym(y)
  
  data[[x]] + data[[y]]
}

sum2vars(mtcars, mpg, am)
#>  [1] 22.0 22.0 23.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4
#> [16] 10.4 14.7 33.4 31.4 34.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 28.3 27.0 31.4 16.8 20.7
#> [31] 16.0 22.4
```

Within the tidyverse you can use the embracing approach

```r
plot2vars <- function(data, x, y) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes(x = {{ x }}, y = {{ y }})) +
    ggplot2::geom_point()
}

plot2vars(mtcars, wt, mpg)
```

[image]

For more details consider reading the [chapter 19](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html) of the book Advance R

And this post on [programming in the tidyverse](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Does exactly what I needed it to. Thank you!